# Async Implementation

Tags: language-design, implementation, async, c#

I have recently been making my own programming language and I am finding most concepts easy to understand, however I'm not sure how to implement async/await in my language.

ATM, I'm using C# to create this language and I have no idea how to go about implementing such features.

The language is an interpreted one.

I'm able to implement a JS-like Promise system, but this doesn't help with running asynchronous C# functions, for example sending a HTTP request.

What I have working with such "promise-like" system is this:

```
var any f = Future.create(|resolve, reject| => resolve(2));
f.then(val => Console.writeLine(val));
```

It works perfectly within the language, however trying to run async C# functions whilst the entire interpreter does not use async at all I have no idea how to do.

The only options I can think of is

1. Make every C# function async (like the parser, interpreter, etc.) by default, but I'm not sure if this would help
2. Use the `.GetAwaitor().GetResult()` but apparently this shouldn't really be used

I've tried searching and looking everywhere on Google for ways to implement this but I could never find any, so any resources for this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: I take it you're writing an interpreter? It would help to make this explicit. By the way, welcome to the site!

Comment: @kaya3 thanks, I've edited my question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'm able to implement a JS-like Promise system, but this doesn't help with running asynchronous C# functions, for example sending a HTTP request.

Async/await is syntax sugar for promises.

You'll need to familiarize yourself with [**Continuation Passing Style (CPS)**](https://matt.might.net/articles/by-example-continuation-passing-style/). Basically, CPS is a way to write regular, sequential ("procedural") code as a chain of callbacks. Ex:

```js
function() {
    let x = foo("a", "b")
    let y = bar("c", "d")
    let z = baz(1, 2, x)
    return y + z
}
```

converted into CPS is

```js
function(k) {
    foo("a", "b", function(x) {
        bar("c", "d", function(y) {
           baz(1, 2, x, function(z) k(y + z))
        })
    })
}
```

This is roughly what your interpreter needs to do with async functions before you interpret them. Convert:

```js
async function() {
    let x = await foo("a", "b");
    let y = await bar("c", "d");
    let z = await baz(1, 2, x);
    return y + z;
}
```

into

```js
function() { return new Promise(resolve => 
    foo("a", "b").then(function(x) {
        bar("c", "d").then(function(y) {
           baz(1, 2, x).then(function(z) resolve(y + z))
        })
    })
}
```

Specifically:

- After parsing an `async` function or other kind of `aysnc` block, desugar it into a regular function which returns a promise, where all the `await`s are replaced with `.then` and `.catch` callbacks.
- If your language supports top-level async, you can parse and desugar the entire source to get one big promise which you then execute. Alternatively, to avoid parsing the entire file at once, you can parse and desugar each *individual statement* into a promise, *waiting to parse the next statement until the promise resolves*. Basically, write an async function `evalRemaining(int pos)`, which lexes/parses and desugars the first statement into a promise, then adds a `.then` callback to that promise which recursively calls `evalRemaining` with the position right after that statement's end.
- If your language supports top-level async in a REPL you handle it similarly: read/lex/parse/desugar the current line into a promise, then wait until that promise resolves before asking the user for the next line, by putting the code to do so in the promise callback.

Now, your goal is to desugar a statement or expression with `await`s, into a promise expression where the `await`s are replaced with `.then` and `.catch` callbacks, and the promise resolves into the expression result. This is essentially the same as converting a block of procedural code into a function written in CPS.

---

There's a lot of existing literature on continuation passing style. You mentioned having trouble finding resources to implement async/await, but if you can rephrase your queries about implementing async/await into implementing CPS conversion, I guarantee you'll find online guides and other resources.

## Rule-based async/await (CPS-style) conversion via [preorder traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order,_NLR)

Like type-checking, computing the derivative in calculus, and other algorithms, one way to do async/await conversion is to create a fixed set of rules which handle general cases and compose into whatever code you may encounter. Specifically, create a rule for every kind of statement which desugars in a special way, and then to desugar an arbitrary statement, run a preorder traversal, processing each sub-statement or expression with the applicable rule.

Here are some of these rules. If your language has unique semantics, you may need to come up with other rules or modify these rules on your own. There are also be optimized rules for more specific cases which will generate faster / smaller code. Lastly, I didn't check these rules, so there may be bugs:

### Async function/block

```js
async function f(...) -> T {
    ...
    <... throw x; ...>
    <... return y; ...>
}
```

converts into

```js
function f(...) -> Promise<T> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ...
        <... resolve(x); ...>
        <... reject(y); ...>
        // In case the function doesn't return anything,
        // add this to the end of the Promise or it'll never resolve
        resolve()
    });
}
```

(e.g. `return foo` gets converted into `resolve(foo)`, `throw bar` gets converted into `reject(bar)`, otherwise code is desugared with the following rules and placed into the promise closure).

Async blocks, if your language supports them (like Rust), are similar:

```rust
async {
    ...
    result
}
```

converts into

```rust
Promise::new(|resolve| {
    ...
    resolve(result)
})
```

#### Desugar from inside out ([preorder traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order,_NLR))

If a statement contains a nested `await` but it's in an `async` function or block, desugar the inner `async` function/block before desugaring the outer one. This also applies to `async` expressions and other rules.

### Statements or expressions without `await`

A sequence of statements without an await is unchanged.

```js
async function() {
    a;
    while (b) { c; d; }
    try { e; } catch { f; } finally { g; }
}
```

converts into

```js
function() -> Promise<()> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        a;
        while (b) { c; d; }
        try { e; } catch { f; } finally { g; }
        resolve();
    });
}
```

### Expression or expression statement

```js
before;
context <... await expr ...> context;
after;
```

becomes

```js
before;
expr.then(e => {
    context <... e ...> context;
    after
});
```

e.g.

```js
let a = foo();
let b = bar(await baz()) * 2;
let c = a + b;
```

becomes

```js
let a = foo();
baz().then(e => {
   let b = e * 2;
   let c = a + b;
});
```

### If statement

```js
if (cond) {
    then;
} else {
    else;
}
rest;
```

If either `then` or `else` contain an `await`, the entire `if` must be converted into a new promise

```js
new Promise(resolveTheIf => {
    if (cond) {
        then.then(resolveTheIf);
    } else {
        else.then(resolveTheIf);
    }
}).then(() => {
    rest;
})
```

(of course, make sure `resolveTheIf` doesn't shadow the outer `resolve` in case `then` or `else` contains a `return` statement).

If `cond` contains an `await`, you can convert into the equivalent:

```js
let c = cond;
if (c) {
    then...
} else {
    else...
}
rest...
```

and then convert from there.

If either `then` or `else` does not contain an `await`, replace `then.then(resolveTheIf)` or `else.then(resolveTheIf)` with `then; resolveTheIf()` or `else; resolveTheIf()` (respectively).

If your `if`/`else` returns an expression like Rust, convert the zero argument call/closure into a one-argument one. Ex:

```rust
let foo = if (cond) {
    await then()
} else {
    else()
}
...
```

converts into

```rust
Promise::new(|resolveTheIf| {
    if (cond) {
        then.then(resolveTheIf);
    } else {
        resolveTheIf(else)
    }
}).then(|foo| {
    ...
})
```

#### While statement

Similar to the above

```js
while (cond) {
    body;
}
rest;
```

if `body` contains an `await, this converts into

```js
const recurse = resolveTheWhile => {
    if (cond) {
        body.then(() => recurse(resolveTheWhile));
    } else {
        resolveTheWhile();
    }
};
new Promise(recurse)
```

If `cond` contains an `await`, you can resolve it before the `while` block.

Like `return` and `throw` when desugaring an async function, `break` desugars into `resolveTheWhile()`. If you have nested `while`s and allow labeling them, so that users can call `break outer` from within the inner loop to break the outer one, you have to call `resolveTheWhile` of `outer` to break the outer loop.

#### Switch and for statements

These can be deduced from the `if` and `while` statements. I'll show an example of a complicated `for` statement.

```js
for (let i = await init(); await cond(i); await update(i)) {
    await body;
}
rest;
```

converts into

```js
init().then(i => {
    const recurse = resolveTheFor => {
        cond(i).then(c => {
            if (c) {
                body.then(() => update(i).then(() => recurse(resolveTheFor)));
            } else {
                resolveTheFor();
            }
        })
    };
}
```

#### Try/catch/finally statement

This is similar to the `if` statement, except that the `catch` block corresponds to a `.catch` promise callback.

```js
try {
    tryCode;
} catch (e) {
    catchCode;
} finally {
    finallyCode;
}
...
```

If either `tryCode`, `catchCode`, or `finallyCode` contain an `await`, you need to convert the entire statement into a promise.

If `tryCode`, `catchCode`, and `finallyCode` all contain `await`s, the entire statement converts into:

```js
new Promise((resolveTheTry, rejectTheTry) => {
    // In general, you should be careful duplicating code when desugaring
    // because it can lead to exponential blowup (imagine what happens if you
    // put finallyCode in the desugared output twice, and then the user writes
    // 32 nested try/finally statements. Language users write that kind of 
    // garbage, then if you're not careful, your interpreter will desugar it
    // into billions or more syntax nodes.
    const finally = (rethrown, e) => {
        finallyCode;
        if (!rethrown) {
            resolveTheTry();
        } else {
            rejectTryTry(e);
        }
    };
    tryCode.then(() => finally(false)).catch(e => {
        catchCode.then(() => finally(false)).catch(e2 => finally(true, e2))
    })
}
```

If any of `tryCode`, `catchCode`, or `finallyCode` don't contain an `await`, you can those into `new Promise(resolve => { code; resolve() })`. There may be optimized variants, but since there are 6 others, I'm not going to compute them all.

A block without a `catch` case

```js
try {
    tryCode;
} finally {
    finallyCode;
}
```

converts into

```js
new Promise((resolveTheTry, rejectTheTry) => {
    const finally = (rethrown, e) => {
        finallyCode;
        if (!rethrown) {
            resolveTheTry();
        } else {
            rejectTheTry(e);
        }
    };
    tryCode.then(() => finally(false)).catch(e => finally(true, e))
});
```

#### Convert a statement or expression without `await` into one with `await`

If necessary, you can convert an expression which doesn't contain `await`

```js
expr
```

into one that does

```js
await new Promise(resolve => resolve(expr))
```

Or a statement

```js
stmt;
```

into

```js
await new Promise(resolve => { stmt; resolve() });
```

Out of the above rules, this is only necessary in the try/catch/finally one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am able to get the promise structure to work (resolve reject, then, catch) etc, but I'm not sure how this would work on the C# backend, as the entire interpreter doesn't use await at all, but if I wanted to run a function such as a http get request, I'm not sure how I'd make this work with the native functions.

Comment: I edited my question to show what I have working.

Comment: Does the native http `request` function take a callback or return a promise? If it does, your `request` wrapper should return a promise object which gets resolved within the callback. If the native function blocks, a non-ideal solution is just to spawn a separate thread or use a thread pool, call the native function, and then call back into the main thread and resolve the promise there.

Comment: I also don't know how you've implemented promises, and whether you have your own async runner or you are using C#'s. If you made your own async runner (you implemented promises without using C#'s async), then you need to integrate it some way with C#'s async runner to call its async functions, and I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure, to call it in C# the only way is to `HttpResponse resp = await HttpClient.GetAsync(url);`

Comment: Since you're using C# async native functions, the wrappers to those native functions like http `request` will be async or return a C# promise ([`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-8.0)). Your inner interpreter needs to be async, but you can wrap it in a function which just calls it and then `ContinueAndWait()` (since your interpreter is the only promise running, and it contains all the promises generated by your code, you can block on it). Then the parser and REPL don't need to be async, even if you're interpreting code as you parse.